# Bulma & scrollTrigger changing/breaking when mobile responsive view set to touch simulation & on actual mobile

Tags: gsap, bulma, scrolltrigger

So I'm using multiple plugins and am having an issue that's prevailed all the way down to stripping everything back to Bulma. When using responsive design mode in Firefox, everything looks exactly as I want it to. When enabling 'touch simulation' or hosting the site and viewing it directly on my phone, it shows it as a slightly different broken version of the edits that I've made.

This further becomes a problem when I'm using GSAP/scrollTrigger and it falls apart even more. With media query on for sccrollTrigger tweens, I suddenly lose my hamburger menu, and multiple sections animations aren't responding at the correct height. Has anyone else had this issue with either platform? Willing to post codepen examples of whatever is necessary.

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Would it be considered odd practice to link the page from my hosted site? There are a lot of external libraries tied into the page.

Comment: It's best practice to make a minimal version of your setup with everything irrelevant stripped out. Preferably something that we can easily run and edit ourselves. Often times you'll figure out the issue just creating the minimal version :)

Comment: The problem is that the issue exists inside of Bulma, and the additional issues exist within scrollTrigger and affects Bulma. Both are plugin libraries that include about 15-20k lines of code each. I believe Codepen allows library linking from weblinks though? I'll try and get it set up in the morning.

Comment: stackoverflow snippet allow you to add external js librabies from CDN, dont't use codepen here.